# Elasticsearch NEST Translation

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I have a search that is giving the correct results and trying to get it to work in .NET Nest but I can't seem to get the correct syntax.   Here is the elastricsearch query that I have:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": { 
      "query": {
        "match": { "formattedName": "Michael" }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {   
            "must": [
                { "term": { "projectId": "5022" } },
                { "term": { "isInvalid": "false" } }
            ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my solution I have the following:

```
var lst = client.Search<EntitySearchItem>(s => s
    .Size(recordCount)
    .Index("entitysearch")
    .Filter(f => f
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(m => m.Term("projectId", projectId), 
                m => m.Term("isInvalid", "false"))))
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(p => p.OnField(f => f.FormattedName).Query(name))));
```

Does anyone familiar with Nest know how I can get the same results?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm new to elasticsearch too so if you have pointers on how to better format the json query I'd appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your elasticsearch query in the example uses [filtered query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-filtered-query.html). You can create one with the NEST just like this:

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<EntitySearchItem>(s => s
    .Index("entitysearch")
    .Query(q => q
        .Filtered(f => f
            .Query(qq => qq
                .Match(m => m.OnField(field => field.FormattedName).Query(name)))
            .Filter(ff => ff.Bool(b => b
                .Must(m => m.Term(t => t.ProjectId, projectId), m => m.Term(t => t.IsInvalid, "false")))))));
```

My `EntitySearchItem` class

```
public class EntitySearchItem
{
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string IsInvalid { get; set; }
    public string FormattedName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're right.  That must have been blurring together.